# Can I include blank field in select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to add an option like  `:include_blank => 'Please Select'`  in a method  `select_tag`  like it is possible with the `select` method? It seems not to work. Is there any substitute for this for `select_tag` method?

Comment: you can unshift a value to your options for select like: `select_tag :selector_name, options_for_select(['option1', 'value1']).unshift(['Blank', '']), :field_value, params...`

Answer (score 47):

In Rails 3 there is a `:prompt` option for `select_tag`:

```
select_tag "things", many_thing_as_options, :prompt => "Please select"
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!  I was trying to prepend a string with HTML to the options helper before I found your answer.

Comment: Oddly enough, include_blank works on select_tag but it does not respect the String being passed to it, so it just shows an empty `<option>` tag, whereas `prompt` will properly show the string passed to it.

Comment: Works in 2.3.8 as well

Answer (score 12):

### **Edit: This answer is only applicable to Rails 2.**

Rails 3 has improved the experience, so you do not have to use this *hack*. [Ahmad hamza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63935645/186039) directly provides the Rails 3 way of answering the question, **as well as providing the more user friendly behaviour of providing a prompt.**

The rest of the response remains as is for any one stuck maintaining a Rails 2 project.

### Original Response

The select_tag method does not modify the options list you pass it. If you want a blank option you have to include it in your list of options.

If you're using options_for_select your list should start with the  *blank* item, ie: `["Please select", '']`.

If you're just passing html to select_tag make sure your first option is:

```
<option value="">Please Select</option>
```

Answer (score 11):

Note that in Ruby on Rails 3, `select_tag()` will accept an `:include_blank` boolean argument (same with date_select and the like).

Comment: Does this have to be a `boolean` or can you pass a String to it that will be displayed?

Answer (score 3):

By passing `include_blank: true` or `prompt: 'Please select'` as a third parameter to `select_tag`

```
<%= select_tag "individual[address][state]", options_for_select(states), { include_blank: true, class: 'form-control' } %>
```

For `prompt`, you can use like this with `select_tag`

```
<%= select_tag "individual[address][state]", options_for_select(indian_states), { prompt: 'Please select', class: 'form-control' } %>
```