# Rails SelectTag include_blank not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am using select_tag and populating it from the database using this.

```
<%= select_tag 'project', options_from_collection_for_select(@issue_statuses,"id", "name"), :include_blank  => 'Select' , html_options = { :onblur => "myblur(this);", :onChange=> "submit_selected(this);", :style=> "visibility:visible;" } %>
```

but on including ":include_blank" i am getting following error:

```
compile error
/home/hitesh/redmine-1.3.0-1/apps/redmine/vendor/plugins/redmine_polls/app/views/questions/index.html.erb:42: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC
...le=> "visibility:visible;" } ).to_s); @output_buffer.concat ...
                          ^
```

how to include blank or prompt value in the above code.

thnx.

Answer (score 4):

Enclose the `:include_blank` call within this: {}

```
<%= select_tag 'project', options_from_collection_for_select([],"id", "name"), {:include_blank  => 'Select', :onblur => "myblur(this);", :onChange=> "submit_selected(this);", :style=> "visibility:visible;" } %>
```

Comment: Well @Arun thnx for your response, but i have already tried that. it gives following error-

Comment: i tried your updated answer. but its not showing any option with 'Select' value. what i want is select box should give prompt option say 'Select Any option'.. i also tried :prompt in place of :include_blank.. but that also dint worked..

Answer (score 2):

Read the post [Can I include blank field in select_tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943106/can-i-include-blank-field-in-select-tag) to get a better understanding of how to use `select_tag`.

If your Rails version is NOT 3.0 or greater then refer to this: 
https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/1987-select_tag-should-allow-include_blank-option to see how to override the default `select_tag` method in `form_tag_helper.rb`

This will add the functionality to `:include_blank => true/false` or `:include_blank => '<String>'`

Good luck.