# Ruby On Rails : configure f.input helper method to have 'Please select' as prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a form in my `Ruby on Rails` project. This is bound to my model. 
I have a `boolean` value, that can take `true` or `false`. 
Instead of using a checkbox to set it I changed it to a select box.

`<%= f.input :test_account, :as => :select, :prompt => true, :include_blank => true %>`

Here I added `:prompt` and `:include_blank` (probably I just need one of these). Currently the select defaults to the "No" value. This is not what I want, I want it to stick to "Please select..." in order to validate that the user made a selection and not just skipped the whole question.

In my model I now have the following to validate it:
`validates_inclusion_of :test_account, :in => [true, false]`

How can I configure it to have 'Please select', 'No', 'Yes' as its values and report an error when the form is submitted but no value has been chosen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943106/can-i-include-blank-field-in-select-tag.  Use the Rails `select_tag` helper for this.

Comment: Maybe relevant: I am using the gem 'simple_form'.

Comment: Is there a default value set in the database?  Put it another way, if you do `foo = YourClass.new; foo.test_account`, what do you get back?

Comment: The column had been created like this: `add_column :projects, :test_account, :boolean, :default => false`

Comment: This seems to be the issue, if I create a boolean without a default value it does work. I am a bit surprised that this can not be overriden on the front-end though (since it's just a database description imho).

Answer (score 1):

**3 states cannot be represented in a boolean.**

I don't know if this is an answer, but your question is interesting. I see this as a data problem, not as a form problem. If I understand your situation, you have 3 testable states of the variable:

- Yes
- No
- Nothing selected

This seems to logically rule out using a boolean. The false state, nil state and the state of nothing selected are all "false", so you have a collision on that state. When you're in the form you don't know if the var is not selected at all, or has been selected as false (unless you do some js listener actions to see if something was clicked).

It looks to me like the solution is to use a string for "Yes" and "No" and nil as the third, nothing-has-been-selected option.

Then, when you validate the existence of the variable with your model then the form validations work as designed.

**Correction/Clarification**

**In Ruby on Rails 3 states can be represented in a boolean**

In case someone comes across this discussion, I thought I'd post the correction after a discussion with SO user @D-side.

For former bit twiddlers this may not seem logical, myself being among them, but it seems that what we think of as booleans in Ruby of Rails are not strictly typed as booleans and do in fact have 3 states. Even in the database, a boolean type may have 3 states.

From the PostgreSQL documentation:

> The boolean type can have several states: "true", "false", and a third state, "unknown", which is represented by the SQL null value.

An excellent Ruby explanation of what I'd call a tri-boolean is below in the discussion with @D-side.

Comment: Database columns are nullable by default. So this is not entirely true.

Comment: Yes. Of course, but is null false or not selected? That's the point I'm making, a boolean has two states possible by definition, and we have a three state situation.

Comment: Depends on how it's processed. One can set up 3 branches having `if flag.nil?` and `elsif flag`, resulting in 3 different branches for `nil`, `true` and `false`. Ruby doesn't respect type safety that much to have "strict booleans".

Comment: Let's drill down. In a microprocessor, a boolean is represented by a bit. One bit. Two states, off/on. Admittedly, I know more about microcode than Ruby, but you're saying in Ruby a boolean can have 3 states? How is this possible? I am truly curious, and would like to know, not being snarky.

Comment: Microprocessor bits contain values, so it's not exactly a fair comparison. Ruby variables contain references to objects that are not type-bounded and as such can point to anything. And the fun part is, **there is no such thing as `Boolean` class in Ruby**, only separate `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` with only instances of them being `true` and `false` respectively. How does the boolean concept work in Ruby at all then? Well, `if` is defined to fire its first branch on all values that are not `false` or `nil`. And even with that `nil == false` returns `false`, they're not the same.

Comment: It's quite the same in Java (that **does** have a `Boolean` class and type-bounded variables). Since all variables holding class instances in Java are referential, the same problem applies: any referential type can contain `null`. So `Boolean`-typed variable can contain `Boolean.TRUE`, `Boolean.FALSE` or `null` (the general null-reference meaning "no value"). It's not just Ruby's oddity.

Comment: That's interesting and good to know. I see what you're saying about Ruby. And if it's not a boolean type, then it needn't be bound by boolean rules. On the other hand, the database table field can be defined as a type BOOLEAN, so I looked that up in PostGreSQL and it reads "The boolean type can have several states: "true", "false", and a third state, "unknown", which is represented by the SQL null value." So, it does seem that in the weird world of RoR a boolean type can have 3 states. Which means it's not a boolean at all. I dub thee a "tri-boolean."

Comment: I've seen some call it "nullable boolean". It's also not unlike a boolean wrapped in a `Maybe`-monad. Also, in [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) there's `Bool` and `Null<Bool>` that only makes a difference on specific export targets (like C++). I may have given you quite a lot of subjects to read up on already, so I'll stop now :)

Comment: Thanks @D-side -- I  like that, "nullable booelan". Will use. Good stuff. I don't know if we helped the asker at all, but I learned some things.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `select` method to generate `Select` dropdown like

Example:

```
select("post", "person_id", Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {include_blank: 'None'})
```

could become:

```
<select name="post[person_id]">
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="1">David</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">Sam</option>
  <option value="3">Tobias</option>
</select>
```

In your case

```
f.select("test_account", ['true', 'false'], {include_blank: 'Please select...'})
```

> Note:
>   `:prompt` appears in the list when there isn't a current value.
>   `:include_blank` appears in the list always.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.input :test_account, :as => :select, :prompt => "Please select"%>
```

Try

```
<%= f.input :test_account, collection: [true,false], prompt: "Please select"%>
```

Comment: If I use that, and open the form to create a new item, the "No" option is active and the "Please select" option is the first in the list of three items in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<%= f.input :test_account, :as => :select, :prompt => "Please select"%>
```